Series about a group of teens who have powers
I remember reading a book about around 4 teens who had some kind of powers. There's one scene at a skating park that I strongly remember. The comic is centered around a kind of pink-ish purple color that appears multiple times. It's about some sort of gem that is that color. The first comic ended on a cliff-hanger. I borrowed it from my local library some years ago but it didn't have the 2nd book so I forgot about it.
In the first book on the first page, there's pictures of the characters with their names and powers. I believe there's also a part where a girl was about to get hit by a football, yet her powers punctured the ball before that happened.
I'll describe the scene at the skating park underneath:
Two girls (the main characters) go to a skating park cause they have to find something related to the antagonist in the comic, they see a sketchy person at the bottom of a half pipe (Thank you Shawn) the person then spots them and runs through a kind of portal/mist thing that they create and the girls follow the person and go to some kind of like carnival fun house, i also kind of remember vines, like poison ivys powers but im not really sure about that bit

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

If you strongly remember the scene at the skate park, what happened?  Was it a dramatic scene, were they attacked, were there wacky hijinks, what?

That's a half pipe, btw
